# How to enlarge a picture in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to enlarge a single picture in WPF. The problem is that after the operation the picture is shown only a part.

And I have to make it enlarged gradually. How can I do it?

Comment: @IonicăBizău sorry for not choosing for such a long time. in fact, this is a question of my friend, so i almost forget it at all.

Comment: Better latter than never. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you modified image stretch property to `none`.

Set `Height` and `Width` attributes:

```
<Image
   Height="165"
   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
   Name="image1" Stretch="Fill"
   VerticalAlignment="Top"
   Width="339"
   Source="[your source]" />
```

In `[your source]` you will put your image's source.

Answer (score 1):

If your image element is showing only part of the picture, you can change the Stretch property to either Uniform, which preserves the aspect ratio, or Fill, which does not.

You can use a ScaleTransform for the RenderTransform property to enlarge the picture without affecting the layout of your application or a ScaleTransform for the LayoutTransform property to enlarge the picture so your layout is affected. ScaleTransform provides two important properties, ScaleX and ScaleY, which affect how the image is resized in its X and Y axes, respectively. To apply this effect gradually, you must use a DoubleAnimation. You don't specify when you want to trigger the enlargement, so for the purpose of example, I'll assume you want the image to be enlarged when the user mouses over the image. The provided code also gradually decreases the image size when the user mouses out of the image. To change when the increase and decrease of size occurs, change the RoutedEvent property of the two EventTriggers.

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="Penguins.jpg">
     <Image.RenderTransform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" x:Name="scale" />
     </Image.RenderTransform>
     <Image.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="scale" To="1.5"
                                          Duration="0:0:1" />
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="scale" To="1.5"          
                                          Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
               <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="scale" To="1" 
                                          Duration="0:0:1" />
                         <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY"
                                          Storyboard.TargetName="scale" To="1" 
                                          Duration="0:0:1" />
                     </Storyboard>
               </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
     </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```